# Columnstore index on memory optimized table in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, columnstore, memory-optimized-tables

Can we create clustered/non-clustered columnstore index on a memory optimized table in SQL Server 2014?

Answer (score 0):

`Columnstore Index` is not supported with memory optimized tables.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't create a columnstore index on a memory optimized table, only nonclustered hash and nonclustered indexes are allowed, see here for more details:

[Guidelines for Using Indexes on Memory-Optimized Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn133166.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

ColumnStore indexes are going to be supported on Top on In-memory/hekaton tables in SQL Server 2016.